# Visual Studio 2017: Error when compiling project in MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset file

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution that includes a project when compiling it returns the following compilation error:

***CS8035   Error reading ruleset file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset - Unable to load file or assembly 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The assembly manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)***

I have no solution for this issue. I've been trying and searching in Google but I still haven't found what is happening with the project. Maybe is a framework installed problem?

Thank you in advanced for your support.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem installing Visual Studio 2019 and compile the solution with it. From now, I have to use VS2019 instead VS2017 to work with the code.